# Let $X, Y ∈ R^{n × m}$. We are looking for an orthogonal matrix $R ∈ M_n (R)$ that minimizes $\|RX - Y\|^2=\operatorname{tr}((RX - Y)^T (RX - Y))$.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I'm trying to show that the wanted matrix is $R = VU^T$, where $XY^T = UΣV^T$ is the singular value decomposition, but I'm having trouble understanding what it means or how to start.

Comment: What is your norm? Is it any natural norm? Also, RHS is square of Frobenius norm $||RX-Y||_F^2$. Maybe that can be helpful.

Comment: Try to differentiate $tr((RX-Y)^\top(RX-Y))$ with respect to $R$.

Comment: @Snowball it is indeed a Frobenius norm, thanks for reminding me, I just don't understand what I need to do to "minimize" it.

Comment: @Mavi you can check this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946911/minimize-the-frobenius-norm-of-the-difference-of-two-matrices-with-respect-to-ma. I think it answers your problem.